# Xcode - changing the number of labels

Tags: swift, xcode, label

Hello I am new to coding and in seek of help. Lately i've been trying to make it so in a label if it get's to a certain number in my case 8 it resets back to 0.

Comment: please explain your problem . it is quite impossible to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let label = UILabel()
var count: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        if count == 8 {
            count = 0
        }
        label.text = "\(count)"
    }
}
```

all you need to do is to increment the **count** where you need, everything else is taking care of by the `didSet` - **reseting count** and **updating label** text.

increment your count as:

```
count += 1 // or the value you need
```